# What's the use of a dimension that is a subset of a fact table?

Tags: data-warehouse, business-intelligence, dimensional-modeling

In the book: 'Hands-On SQL Server 2019 Analysis Services'; the author presents this model.

In the center I see Sales and InvoiceSales as fact tables... My question is regarding the Invoice dimension, it only has 2 columns which are already present in InvoiceSales, why did he add it?

[image]

note: the InvoiceSales fact table has the InvoiceDateKey column.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a business need as a `Snapshot Fact Tables`:

> Snapshot Fact Tables
>
> (Periodic) Snapshot fact tables capture the state of the measures
> based on the occurrence of a status event or at a specified
> point-in-time or over specified time intervals (week, month, quarter,
> year, etc.).